# stimulsoft - Put chart in Group Header

Tags: charts, stimulsoft

I want to make a graphical report (Chart) with stimulsoft and show for example how many items have been sold by each seller.

for example =>

Seller one
Item1  - 20

Item2  - 20

Item3  - 40

Item4  - 5

============

Seller two

Item1  - 2

Item2  - 45

Item3  - 1

Item4  - 0

I use groupheaderband with its conditions and put chart on it. 
Group is doing fine but chart is showing all data in each iteration. For example:

Seller one => full chart

Seller two => full chart

But i need to have a chart for each one not total

Answer (score 0):

You should set a Filter for the chart. The current value of the Group should be stored in a variable.